# Woocommerce shop manager role, hide woocommerce menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am using a wordpress theme which supports woocommerce, 
when adding a user with shop manager role i don't want to show the woocommerce menu.

Just need the products menu only.

please help.

[image: what i need]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use WordPress's '[remove_menus()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)' function to do this.

Store Managers have a capability: 'manage_woocommerce'

You can see that they are allowed to see the WooCommerce admin menu here:
'/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-menus.php'

Look for: `$main_page = add_menu_page( __( 'WooCommerce', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'WooCommerce', 'woocommerce' ), 'manage_woocommerce', 'woocommerce' , array( $this, 'settings_page' ), null, '55.5' );`

So much for the theory. To stop this admin menu item from displaying for anyone but an Administrator, add this to your functions.php file or plugin:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){

    // If the current user is not an admin
    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

        remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce' ); // WooCommerce admin menu slug

    }
}
```

Comment: You could add slugs for the other WooCommerce admin pages too in case users find a back door by appending the slug. Just add new lines as per the Codex. The slugs for the pages are visible in the 'class-wc-admin-menus.php' file mentioned above.

Comment: how to remove sub menu of woocommerce ( admin.php?page=wc-status )
i use : remove_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'wc-status' );
it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the rep points to add a comment, but needs to change the hooked action from:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

to:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menus' );
```

and then you can do something like:

```
function remove_menus(){

    // If the current user is not an admin
    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

        remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-status');

    }
}
```

if you are trying to remove core woocommerce submenu items.

(responding to Do Xuan Nguyen's comment)